# The relationship of earth frame and map frame

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, tf-tree

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow the instruction of  [REP:105](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html). As it mentioned to have the map frame corrected by the earth frame. So I use imu_filter_madgwick with 9-axis sensor to produce the absolute orientation of the earth and map. Then, use the function provided by the same package to produce the earth and map correction in /tf tree.

However, what I got is the following. the mapping will constant rotation of the map. Hence the rotational mapping result.
[Mapping in RVIZ](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iGBb34vwYVlJtnkmdHO6OBOlM9jpxHZw/view?usp=sharing)

This is my /tf tree.
[TF Tree](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eFv-UeO0jUkG4RIx7vCiyF4Vq9afppWA/view?usp=sharing)

There must be some misunderstanding for me.
Please help clarify it.
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382051/the-relationship-of-earth-frame-and-map-frame/) by [jacklu333333](https://answers.ros.org/users/68134/jacklu333333/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2021-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would expect the transform from earth->map to be a constant. Any movement of the robot has no effect on the relationship of those 2 frames.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacklu333333](https://answers.ros.org/users/68134/jacklu333333/) on 2021-07-09**:
Hi, thank you for your reply. You point out my blind spot about the relationship of earth->map frame. It should be constant since the map->odom, the rotation measurement would be here.

In that case, I am wondering how can I publish the earth->map relationship at the initial state dynamically since we cannot always assume the North is match to y-asix (for xyz to enu configuration).

Once again thank you for the clarification.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-09**:
If you build a map with `rtabmap' and save it, you can then calculate the static rotation needed based on where the map x-axis ended up. Doing this dynamically is more difficult: you will need to read the initial magnetic orientation of the robot once before you begin the rtabmap mapping procedure.

**Comment by [jacklu333333](https://answers.ros.org/users/68134/jacklu333333/) on 2021-07-12**:
Thank you for the clarification.

In that case, wouldn't the earth frame a little bit ineffective in most cases since it is always static?

The only case we can apply the earth frame will be when there are multiple robots to do multi-session mapping, in addition, we need to calibrate the orientation of each robot in advance or read once at the beginning.

Is my understanding correct?

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-12**:
It's not clear on what you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to 1) create a single, combined map or 2) keep a unique map for each robot and be able to convert between the different map's coordinate systems or 3) something else.

**Comment by [jacklu333333](https://answers.ros.org/users/68134/jacklu333333/) on 2021-07-12**:
I think it's more close to 2. Since I want to map the environment as a global map. With the information given by you, I think I can make it work. Thanks a lot.

I am just curious about the necessity of earth frame. Since I can just rotate the map at the mapping session so that XYZ will match to the ENU, in that case, the [REP:105](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html) seems unnecessary to define the earth frames, right?

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-12**:
*Since I can just rotate the map at the mapping session so that XYZ will match to the ENU*

REP:105 is showing a general architecture. If you choose to transform a rotated map, or somehow pre-initialize the mapN frame so the axes are what you want, then each earth->mapN transform is the Identity transform. Which approach is easiest depends on what you know, and when you know it.

**Comment by [jacklu333333](https://answers.ros.org/users/68134/jacklu333333/) on 2021-07-13**:
I got it. Thank you for your time and the detailed explanation.

**Comment by [xdzye](https://answers.ros.org/users/125007/xdzye/) on 2023-01-18**:
@Mike Scheutzow

Can you explain to me how to calculate the static rotation from RTABMap map_frame to my own custom coordinate system? How do I find out, where the axes of the ROS coordinate system point to after running rtabmap and/or dynamically and how much I need to rotate it to fit my custom coordinate system?
The translation part is already working inside rtabmap with the help of [Marker/Priors](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/blob/master/corelib/include/rtabmap/core/Parameters.h#L788) parameter by setting global coordinates for the known accurate positions of the markers and detecting exactly these markers in local coordinates in the map_frame. This translates the coordinate origin to the right origin of my global coordinate system. Unfortunately, the rotation does not work. Can I do this with the help of your suggestion and export/apply the rotation somehow on to the map/earth_frame?